# Oracle datetime in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have a Oracle procedure to which I have to pass a datetime value (2/5/2010 11:46 AM)
How do I pass this value from VB.net. When I pass the date as shown below it is not returning any records though there are records.

```
With Cmd
                .Connection = FactsConn
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                .CommandText = "sp_atas_image_qry"
                .Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("vinspectiondatetime", OracleClient.OracleType.DateTime)).Value = "2/5/2010 11:46 AM"
                .Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("io_cursor", OracleClient.OracleType.Cursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably send a `DateTime` object, not a `String`:

```
.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("vinspectiondatetime", OracleClient.OracleType.DateTime)).Value = new DateTime(2010, 2, 5, 11, 46, 0)
```

Comment: VB.Net supports DateTime literals.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the parameter value to a string.

You need to set it to a `DateTime` value, like this: `#2/5/2010 11:46 AM#`