# Using parameters for date in Oracle query

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have a set of queries I am running out of VB.NET codebehind on a web page that read a user's input for start and end dates. Here is the code/query:

```
strOraQuery = "SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3 " & _
              "FROM a_table a LEFT JOIN b_table b ON (a.col1=b.col1) " & _
              "WHERE a.datecol BETWEEN :startdate AND :enddate"

oracmd = New OracleCommand(strOraQuery, oracn)    
oracmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":enddate", strEndDate))
oracmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":startdate", strStartDate))
```

EDIT #2: These parameters are actually out of order in my code, so I flipped them to show the issue that I was actually having. Refer to answers/comments below.

strStartDate and strEndDate are both in mm/dd/yyyy format.

This bit of code runs the query through a DataReader and into a DataTable. The error I am receiving from running the query is

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was
>   expected

I have tried to change the query and the Parameters.Add() statement around in at least a dozen different ways and nothing has worked yet. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

EDIT:

The start and end dates are global variables declared and set like so:

```
Dim strStartDate As String
Dim strEndDate As String

Protected Sub btnRun_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click
     strStartDate = txtStartDate.Text
     strEndDate = txtEndDate.Text
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` in application session is not equal to `MM/DD/YYYY`. That's why implicit char-to-date conversion fails.

You should use DateTime object and not a String one in OracleParameter constructor. Please, [read this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2465124/2455587).

Another solution is to convert string parameter to date explicitly:

```sql
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3
  FROM a_table a LEFT JOIN b_table b ON (a.col1=b.col1)
 WHERE a.datecol BETWEEN to_date(:startdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND to_date(:enddate, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Format mask parameter in `TO_DATE` has higher priority than session NLS settings.

Comment: I tried both of those again and neither worked... I'm stumped. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please, show declaration and value assignment for `strEndDate` and `strStartDate`.

Comment: Question updated to show the variable declaration and assignment

Comment: Bah... Nevermind. I figured it out. Looks like my parameters were out of order in my code, which I just found out is not okay. I typed it up a little differently in here because I can't copy and paste my exact code. Thank you for your help! Your solution is technically correct, so you get the accept.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the edit to my question, the parameters I set were out of order which is not allowed by default in ODP.NET. Parameters are bound by order unless this line of code is included

```
OracleCommand.BindByName = True
```

This is noted in [this thread](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/217870) over at the Oracle forums.